# Unable to chown after failed nfs4_setfacl with sec=sys?

Tags: nfsv4

I’m mounting a remote file system with NFSv4.1 and sec=sys on a CentOS7 client with nfs-utils-1.3.0-0.66. Interacting with the mount works as expected with UIDs/GIDs until I attempt to set an NFSv4 ACE with a local username (e.g. `nfs4_setfacl -a “A::myuser:rwatTnNcy” myfile`). The nfs4_setfacl command returns: `Failed setxattr operation: Invalid argument` and some odd translation seems to get cached as chown stops working (chown returns: `chown: changing ownership of ‘myfile’: Invalid argument`). It seems the only way to correct the issue is to remount the NFS share. I’ve tried restarting nfs-idmapd (and disabling the service), I’ve confirmed `/sys/module/nfs/parameters/nfs4_disable_idmapping` is enabled, and I’ve tried clearing the keyring with `nfsidmap -c`, but I’m still unable to chown until the share is remounted.

Am I looking in the wrong place? Ideally, nfs4-acl-tools would translate the local user to a UID rather than use username@domain (the NFS server appears to accept UIDs when they’re explicitly provided with nfs4_setfacl), but it’s more important that chown can be used after a failed nfs4_setfacl.